# How to access the values in bindingContext.ValueProvider?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDlFD.png)

I was wondering how to access the values in bindingContext.ValueProvider, i.e. the values on the right of the picture like "System.Web.Mvc.FormValueProvider", etc. I've tried different versions of GetValue(key) but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `bindingContext.ValueProvider.TryGetValue(key, out valueResult);`?

Answer (score 0):

For MVC Core 1.0,

For URL http://localhost:8000/api?param1= 123445

```
var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("param1");
```

Acces value with `value.FirstValue`